# : Operator in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, operators

What this code mean in VB.NET ? 
I don't understand with `:` operator.
Is it same with ternary operator in Java/C#/C ?

```
 If InStr(elementName, "*") > 0 And depth < maxDepth Then isRule = True : isGrRule = True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VB.NET, colon `:` is used to put two statements in one line and acts as a separator for those statements.

See more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba9sxbw4.aspx):

> To place multiple statements on the same line
>
> Separate the statements with a colon (:), as in the following example.
>
> text1.Text = "Hello" : text1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red

It has nothing to do with the ternary operator in Java/C#/C.